# Which component based Java-Framework can also do Webservices?

Tags: java, rest, frameworks, wicket, tapestry

For a new project I want to usa a component-based framework (thinking of Wicket or Tapestry). It's an intranet-application, but i have to provide Restful Webservices aswell.

After googling around i havent found any good solution, that describes how to integrate Wicket with any Jax-RS compliant library.

Has anybody done this before?

I already saw, that Wicket CAN provide rest-like URLs, but i would to switch between fully-fledged Wicket-Gui and webservice by accept-header.

Everything i found, suggests, creating a different vhost/url-route.

If you say, tapestry (or any other framework) is much better, for what i wanna do, let me know. But somehow i like wicket.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Play. It is quite easy to learn and very powerful, with lots of shelf life ahead.

Comment: I've tried Play and yeah, I somehow liked it. But i directly used the 2.0rc and encountered some bugs. Doesnt seem to be enterprise ready for me. I have to use a legacy oracle Database. 1.st bug i encountered: ebean doesnt support OnToMany with a seperate JoinTable. Its mentioned on some mailinglist, but doesnt seem to be fixed. 2nd: i tried anorm with scala. This cant handle BigInt indices that come from our Database. Enough play for me. :( But it definitly hase some realy nice aspects, if you maybe start from scratch.

Comment: If you want one framework to provide both "normal" web access and REST, Wicket is definitely not the framework to have. However, integrating any such framework with Wicket is easy, as the entry point of Wicket is a single servlet filter, mapped to a base url. So all you need to do is to map your REST framework to another url.

Comment: Okay... I'l have a look at another framework. Maybe Tapestry or even Spring. Btw: I've found a mailinglist-entry which is almost one year old: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/be52c361ba37aed7 this guy is having the same anorm-problem with play2.0 that i had in rc3. So for me it doesnt seem to be Production ready with legacy databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using Spring "contract first" web services or REST:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html

Especially if you're interested in frameworks.  Spring is *much* more than a web MVC framework.  It gives you:

1. Dependency injection
2. Aspect oriented programming
3. Rock solid modules for web MVC, persistence, remoting, messaging, security, web services, etc.

I'm not sure why you think a component based approach is superior, but it seems to me that it's been left in the dust by HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery.  I'd reconsider the requirement.

The implementation of the web service should not know or care at all about what technology is used to implement the client.  That's the beauty of web services: if done properly, they can survive longer.  UIs can come and go, but the business logic and fundamentals in the services can remain.  They can deal with UIs running on desktops, browsers, mobile, and maybe even Google's heads-up display.  We'll see.

Comment: I agree that spring rocks and is very good at web services, but... it's not component based like he asked for.

Comment: Never tried Spring. Thought component-based frameworks would be more suitable for intranet (more productive), because there you dont need the hottest and fanciest ui. It just needs to work. Am i wrong?

Comment: No way.  If the marketplace is correct, then you have to be wrong.  I see much more support for web UIs based on HTML, CSS, JavaScript and especially jQuery.  Tapestry and JSF are dead and have been for a long time.

Comment: Okay, thanks i'll accept your answer because you encouraged me to try spring. Anyway: Do you know any ebook or crud-tutorial to get started? A sample with forms and database acces would be nice too :D

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the classical component based web frameworks (jsf, wicket, etc.) vs. action based web frameworks (spring-mvc or struts).  So in that case, no, POJO != component.  I also agree on you comment about Tapestry and JSF being dead.  Having used JSF, it couldn't have died soon enough.

Comment: Tapestry dead? I notice it's getting used more and more lately

Answer (score 1):

Neither Play, nor Spring MVC is component based. 
In Wicket 1.5 you can roll your own IRequestMapper that checks the header(s) and decides whether to use the default processing (component-based) or to use your custom IRequestHandler that will deliver JSON, XML, ... See TextRequestHandler for inspiration. Your custom IRequestMapper should be set as 'root' to be able to get the incoming requests first, see the usages of HttpsMapper and CryptoMapper for example.
Feel free to ask for more details in the users@ mailing list.